# I can't search "textbox" more than once

Tags: c#

This is my first application in C#.

I'm trying to search an 'ID' in an Excel sheet and print the person details on address label and add to Excel sheet that he is registered (column P_Reg = 0 not registered yet or 1 is registered).

So in the end I can print the list of people who registered.

And to save, quit the Excel after every person because without it I received error that the xlsx file for read only, the save and quit work fine but the search box works, but only once.

Example:

When I search for the first time it works
but when I try for the second time nothing happen

Do I have to use `foreach` or something?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public string fo
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { label1.Text = value; }
    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form2_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        string path = @"D:\Book1.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook workBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[1];//Range of Column A
        Excel.Range findRange;
        string strToFind = label1.Text;
        string valueInColumnB;
        string valueInColumnC;

        // SEARCH
        findRange = range.Find(strToFind);
        if (findRange is null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("id not found");
            this.Close();                
        }
        else
        {
            valueInColumnB = workSheet.Cells[findRange.Row, 2].value;
            valueInColumnC = workSheet.Cells[findRange.Row, 3].Value;

            // Register & SAVE 
            workSheet.Cells[findRange.Row, 4].value = "1";
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            workBook.Save();                

            label2.Text = valueInColumnB;
            label3.Text = valueInColumnC; 

            // PRINT
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            var pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += (s, ev) =>
            {
                var bmp = new Bitmap(800, 800);
                this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Size));
                ev.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, ev.MarginBounds.Location);
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
            };
            PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("", 170, 350);
            var dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            dlg.Document = pd;
            pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 20;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;

            pd.Print();
            this.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to search something multiple times you have to repeat that search until you find nothing more... I dont know the Excel.Range class exactly. but if there is a find method, maybe there is a findnext method too, or the find method can be called multiple times...

Comment: You're executing this code on the `Load` event. typing something else in the search box won't raise the `Load` event again.

Comment: Put the code in a `search` function and call it from a button_Click of maybe even from the textbox.TextChanged event..!

Comment: @TaW 
can you explain how, because the search box and the the search button are in Form1
the search results in Form2
how do i call the search function in form2 from form1

thanks

Comment: Calling a function or working on controls or variables in another form is the most common issue all beginners face and one of the most often asked questions here. The answer goes like this: You need a valid reference to the other Form and you need to make the controls or variablse `public` or at least `internal` (recommended). - If Form1 opens Form2, the reference part is simple for one way: make Form2 a class level variable. Done. For the other way pass out Form1 in the open command: `Form2 = new Form2(this);`; delcare a Form1 variable in Form2 and set it in the constructor. Done..

Comment: @TaW thanks a lot
now everything works, one more question: after i published the application the search don't work anymore, it works in the visual studio but after the publish it stops , but adding new data to the excel database still work after the publish

thanks again

Comment: Hard to tell. Is it on a different machine? Different Paths, Office installation? Any eerors?

Comment: @TaW it's on the same machine, same path and office is installed, no errors
just the message that i entered in case the id not found